# How to set java heap size on Openshift Origin PAAS

Tags: java, cassandra, paas, openshift-origin

I have recently got my instance of Openshift Origin up and running. I deployed my first app. I am creating a "diy (do it yourself) cartridge". I added a Cassandra Cartridge to this app and attempted to run it. Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
xss =  -ea -Xss4m -javaagent:./cassandra/versions/1.2.5/bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms256M -Xmx256M -Xmn80M    -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k
[test-dsx.dsx.org 5283b2358000fdc2a100023a]\> 
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I am unfamiliar with using PAAS and am trying to figure out how to set my java opts in this environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed it by editing `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`

I have changed `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss180k"` to `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss256k"`

and it worked.

[See my question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22470628/1740715)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the stack size setting for java is being overwritten in the command line.  Notice the last token at the end of the invocation: `-Xss180k`.  You need to remove this from the command and then the earlier `-Xss4m` setting will take effect.

If you could specify the url of the cassandra cartridge you used, I'll happily take a look.