# Cassandra:The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k

Tags: cassandra, jvm, stack, ubuntu-14.04, javaagents

I'm getting this error when starting `cassandra` after upgrade. Any idea?

```
# cassandra -f

xss =  -ea -javaagent:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar -XX:+UseThreadPriorities 
-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 -Xms1920M -Xmx1920M -Xmn200M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Xss180k

The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have fixed it by editing file `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh`

I have changed `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss180k"` to `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss256k"`

and it worked.

Basically the value of parameter `Xss` determines stack size. As the error indicates, It is too small. Just by increasing Xss will solve the problem. It was 180K before and I have increased to 256K. It can be different in different machines according to the size of database.