# Stack Size Configuration Option in Apache Cassandra Config File?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I installed Apache Cassandra with Zulu JDK 8 on an M1 Mac. Every time I try to start a server with `./cassandra -f` in the `bin` folder I get an error saying,

```
The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 384k
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Based on the error message I followed this question's solution,

[Cassandra:The stack size specified is too small, Specify at least 228k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470628/cassandrathe-stack-size-specified-is-too-small-specify-at-least-228k)

And tried to edit the `/etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh` config file but I don't find a `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss <...>"` line there, is there something else I should be editing? I'm a beginner trying to setup Cassandra for the first time.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see a jvm.options file?

Comment: @Andrew thanks! I found the option in the jvm.options file. There was a stack size argument set to 256k. Best, Akash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrew,

I could find the stack size declaration in the jvm.options file, under `GENERAL JVM SETTINGS`.

Changing,

```
# Per-thread stack size.
```

from `-Xss256k` to `-Xss400k` did the trick.